# Dynamic regular expression in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

I want to extract currency sign by regex in table's column name and it could be(I am doing it for USD combinations(valid ones - USD, US$, $) now but in actual, I have to iterate one list of currency from config file and make generic regex and then I will use that regex to parse all the column of all tables):

- Alpha USD -> USD
- Alpha_US$ _> US$
- Alpha($) -> $
- Alpha_$$ -> X
- Alpha{USD} -> USD
- Alpha(USDOCOLAND} -> X
- Alpha (multiple spaces) USD -> USD
- USD Alpha -> USD
- Alpha USD USD -> USD
- USD -> USD
- Alpha USD$ -> X

X means no extraction
All above cases are interchangeable with any valid currency symbol coming from config file.

Basically, I have to border the word and it could be surrounded by special characters though.

I am using Scala and create `Regex` object by invoking `.r` on regex string

I have tried using `\b(US\$|USD)\b` for two possible combinations but it can be appended with more currency symbols by looping list from config file. Problem with this one is from string `gfgh (US$f) (US$) (USD) USD`, it matches USD properly and for `US$`, it matches with 2nd word and not 4th one. I am trying to workaround to get `US$` match as expected (3rd word in my example).

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. Look to solve this without a regex. Your program will be simpler to understand and work as well or better.

Comment: Your question should contain your own attempts at solving the problem and any specific issues you have to make it work.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sorry all for badly phrased question, I am making edits..

Comment: @Grismar Updated, sorry

Comment: @rsjaffe I don't want to do without regex and how do you recommend these cases without regex? Column name would be random string, I could have done something like "contains" on string but that will be error prone as I don't want word like USDalpha to be picked up, please suggest if you have better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not match `(US$)` because the word boundary `\b` does not match between `$)`.

One way to match your example data might be to use alternations and lookarounds:

```
(?<={)USD(?=})|(?<=\()USD(?=\))|\bUSD(?![\S$])|(?<=\()(?:US)?\$(?=\))|US\$(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fSUOrZ/1) | [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/aODTYa)

That will match:

- `<={)USD(?=})` Match USD surrounded by {}
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\()USD(?=\))`Match USD surrounded by ()
- `|` Or
- `\bUSD(?![\S$])` Match USD when not followed by a non-whitespace char or `$`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\()(?:US)?\$(?=\))` Match optional `US` followed by `$` surrounded by ()
- `|` Or
- `US\$(?!\S)` Match US$ when not followed by a non-whitespace char

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I played with Lookahead and Lookbehind assertions and looks like it is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that passes all but 2 of your test cases.

```
val txt = Vector("Alpha USD"         // -> USD
                ,"Alpha_US$"         // _> US$
                ,"Alpha($)"          // -> $
                ,"Alpha_$$"          // -> X desired but $ found
                ,"Alpha{USD}"        // -> USD
                ,"Alpha(USDOCOLAND}" // -> X
                ,"Alpha    USD"      // -> USD
                ,"USD Alpha"         // -> USD
                ,"Alpha USD USD"     // -> USD
                ,"USD"               // -> USD
                ,"Alpha USD$"        // -> X desired but USD found
                )

val re = """(US[D$]|\$)(?:\W|$)""".r.unanchored
txt.map{
  case re(a) => a
  case _ => "X"
}
```

In the future, if you want people to help you out, please post test code in a format that can be easily copied and implemented.

Comment: Thanks man, I will keep your suggestion in mind from next time and appreciate your help. Have a good one!